# How could a water boatman bug get in a place with no water?

Tags: entomology, limnology

I built a pond in my backyard. Before I even topped it off, I started finding water boatman (Corixidae) swimming in there.

Note that the nearest body of water from my home is 30 miles away, and its about 1/2 acre in size. There are dry river beds, dry canals, and even a dry lake nearby, but I've never seen water there in 5 years being here.

So how is it that water boatman can show up so suddenly in my pond?

Answer (score 1):

- In animals some species migrate, some hibernate and some aestivate to
  overcome the unfavorable conditions such as desiccation.
- Some aquatic organisms enters into diapause during unfavorable conditions.

Source: [toppr](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/some-organisms-suspend-their-metabolic-activities-to-survive-in-unfavourable/), also see [Gemmule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemmule) (in sponges)